# Foreach Twig 2 arrays simultaneous

Tags: php, symfony, foreach, twig

```
 foreach (array_combine($courses, $sections) as $course => $section)
```

I want to achieve this as well in twigs I have tried this

```
   {% for user in allusers , bd in bds %}
```

but it doesn't work any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can loop through one, and get the desired data from the other based on the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write your own twig extension for array_combine